# Google MBA Service Account get all locations

Tags: service-accounts, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

My company owns several (verified) facilities and using my company's email i can see those locations (business.google.com).
[image]

Now, my company would like to fetch the reviews in each location and present it in our company website. Before we're using the Google Place API but since it only returns the latest 5 reviews we opt to using Google My Business API to retrieve a location's complete reviews. We'd like our backend (PHP) to retrieve the reviews so using the same email I created a service account (console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) because we don't need the end user to allow/interact anything when browsing our website.
[image]

Using postman (with my signed JWT) I have managed to get a valid access token
[image]

...that I use to retrieve the lists of accounts (mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts) I could see the service account itself alone in the response.[image]

Now, I tried calling the account locations api (mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{MY_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE}/locations) but it only returns and empty object response.

[image]

Can someone help me resolve this issue. Why my service account can't see the verified locations under my company's email. Is this even possible? Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately i ran into the same issues... did you solve that in the meantime?

Comment: Do you have a web application client ID for the private My Business API yet? Your credentials screenshot seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Even that this is an older question - I run into the same issue calling the new Google My Business Information v1 API (getting empty results) using a service account.

It seems, that it is not recommended to use Service Accounts, I found this support article on Google: https://support.google.com/business/thread/8281160/cannot-get-access-to-gmb-locations-with-service-account-with-nodejs?hl=en

The "official" recommendation is to use OAuth.

But we finally made it using Service Account. The following steps are necessary to resolve it (at least for us it is working now):

- Add a project in Google Cloud Platform
- Add and enable the Account Management and Business Information API's.
- Add the service account and generate a key (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)
- Make the Business Profile API request (you need the approval made by Google to be able to make requests against the two API's; otherwise you may run into quota exceeds as "Request per minute" is set to 0 by default). Important: It may take up to 2 weeks until, but we received the approval within about 5 days
- Enable domain-wide delegation for the service account using the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage". More about domain-wide-delegation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
- Add a user identity in GCP. This user also needs to be added in Google My Business for editing locations. When creating your ServiceAccountCredential object, impersonate this user.

Security concerns:

- Domain-wide-delegation enables that everyone knowing/having the credentials of the service account could impersonate any person (identity) from withing GCP. At least in this case only for Business Profile API, but anyway, keep this in mind.
- Also using private keys for authenticating the service account is not recommended, you should be aware to regularly change / create a new private key or there would be a solution with Identity Workload.

Hope this helps everyone facing the challenge with GMB / GCP / service accounts :-)

Comment: Just if someone still is interested: we just got this statement of Google support: "Unfortunately, we don't officially support service accounts in the Google My Business API, if you are having issues we recommend you OAuth directly into the Google Account that manages the business listings you are trying to access rather than using a service account to impersonate the account."

Comment: thanks for the update, we face the same issue. Just out of curiosity, did you use OAuth in the end or some other method?

Comment: Sorry for the late response... As mentioned in the answer, we have used the service account (following the described steps it works).

Comment: Do you have to sign-up and pay for google workspaces to enable domain-wide-delegation?

Answer (score 2):

At some point since this was answered, much of the GMB API (including the "accounts.locations" resource)  has been deprecated and replaced by the [Business Profile APIs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/ref_overview), but I made it here when I encountered basically the same issue trying to use a service account with the updated method: ([accounts.locations.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list)) from the [My Business Business Information API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest) *<not a typo...the name of the API repeats "business" 2x...LOL!>*.

I was actually able to get it to work without having to enable domain-wide delegation by granting the Service Account access as a Manager from the Business Profile Manager UI.  It is easy enough to add the Service Account on the BPM UI by clicking on Group Settings -> Manage Users -> Add Users but then it will show the Service Account as invited and there is no way to retrieve that invite to accept it from any UI...but you can do it with the API.

Once the Service Account is invited to be a manager of the Group in BPM, you can use the [Account Management API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest) to accept the invite with this sequence:

1. **[accounts.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list)** - Retrieve the Account_ID for the Service Account from the Log.
2. **[accounts.invitations.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts.invitations/list)** - Use Account_ID from previous step in the query string.  In the Log you will see the Invitation ID of the pending invite.
3. **[accounts.invitations.accept](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts.invitations/accept)** - Use Invitation_ID from previous step in the query string.

This will accept the invitation and you can confirm it worked on the BPM UI by clicking on group settings again.

Once I did that, I was able to use the Service Account to run a single script that retrieved all reviews from 51 different locations based on the group access and without using Domain-Wide Delegation .

I posted the scripts on GitHub if interested: [Google_Service_Accounts](https://github.com/RedBird-Intel/Google_Service_Accounts)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I managed to make it work using your description.
Random note; Using this solution I had to remove the business.manage scope in order to list accounts, but otherwise smooth.

Comment: @ChristianM.P. Which scope did you replace it with?

Comment: @carruw none, I removed scoping entirely when using this approach. When I had the `business.manage` scope attached, as otherwise would be the norm, I couldn't list accounts.