# Cannot fetch locations from Google "My Business Business Information" API service

Tags: google-api, google-business-profile-api, google-business

We want to fetch all locations for a Google My Business profile. We have created a service account, enabled the business APIs and given the service account access to the APIs.

When we try to fetch the locations from the API, we get `HTTP 200 OK` as response, but the response body is empty:

```
request: https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/{serviceAccountId}/locations?readMask=title

response: {}
```

We have added the locations to a group in the Google Business Profile Manager and added the service account as an owner. As someone else with the same problem did earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290367/1329433

Yet we get no locations in from our API call.

Has anybody experienced the same issue? If so, how did you solve it?